# Cannot start Fuchsia Emulator on Ubuntu

Tags: fuchsia

I am trying to build `Fuchsia OS` and run it on the Fuchsia Emulator `femu`, but after waiting for the emulator to start the `fx` command exists and displays the error below.

```
failed to create Fuchsia device device health check failed. Unable to ssh due to error:
Error: Cannot start Fuchsia Emulator. Exit status is 1
```

I have followed the instructions provided by Google at [fuchsia.dev](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/build_fuchsia), the build completes successfully and the commands used to build the OS were

```
fx set core.qemu-x64 --with //examples/hello_world
fx build
```

Subsequently, I tried running in `headless` mode with `fx vdl start -N --headless` which results in the same error as above, I also tried build the OS without the `--with` argument but received the same error.

The [log file](https://pastebin.com/6scqCtwR) gives us more details, the second last line of the log file may be of interest and it reads:

`emu-system-x86_64-headless: network script /etc/qemu-ifdown failed with status 256`

I am using `Ubuntu 21.04` on my machine.

Comment: Does `fx qemu`  work for you? And maybe `fx qemu -N` ?

Comment: @Marco those commands resulted in the same issue as above, I came across your question and tried the same on my system :). Installing the qemu package as suggested by gnoliyil resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the network configuration scripts /etc/qemu-ifup and /etc/qemu-ifdown are missing. You can work around it by installing the qemu package:

$ sudo apt install qemu

Comment: Hm, fuchsia includes prebuilts for qemu, maybe they need to bundle these scripts as well?